# Deploy SharePoint and Power Automate solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, solution

I have a solution based on SharePoint lists and a Power Automate solution. I know that there is a way to deploy the Power automate solution, but what about the SharePoint lists? There are three, and I don't know if there is another way to deploy them, aside from re-creating them in the deployed site.

I know there is a way to import lists with SharePoint Designer, but I wonder if there is a more "modern" solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of SharePoint List solution package you're talking about, either sandboxed solution (deprecated) or the new SPFx package. Aside from that, there are many ways to deploy SharePoint List **without** solution package, such as with PowerShell script or manually create just like Austin mentioned before.

The latest procedure of packaging SharePoint List is described in the Microsoft site via SPFx package, under assets. Do note that this method is slower, and **NOT** very popular unless if you are restricted to deploy or create site or probably just for the sake of documentation of the solution.

In summary:

1. Create an SPFx package (if you don't have one) or modify existing if you're already have for your solution.
2. Create `assets` folder under `sharepoint`.
3. Add `elements.xml` under `assets` folder and define your SharePoint List schema there.
   [image: assets folder]
4. Add another XML for elements and upgrade solutions (in case you want to update the SharePoint List schema in the future).
5. Modify your package-solution.json to include those schemas.
6. Package it with `gulp package-solution` and give the generated solution *.sppkg to SharePoint Admin to deploy.

If you know how to build SharePoint List XML manifest and elements, you're good to go. The method derived from the **exact same schema** when we used to have on-premises solution package to deploy webparts. If not:

- [Understanding Schema.xml files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ms459356(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Understanding Feature xml schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ms460318(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Provision SharePoint assets with solution package - from scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/provision-sharepoint-assets)
- [Provision SharePoint assets with solution package - from tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package)

The last 2 links are similar in nature but complementing each other. I do recommend read both.